# $\frac{a}{a^{2}+b^{2}+2}+\frac{b}{b^{2}+c^{2}+2}+\frac{c}{c^{2}+d^{2}+2}+\frac{d}{d^{2}+a^{2}+2}\le 1$

Tags: inequality, summation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let be a,b,c,d non negative real numbers. Prove that :

$$\frac{a}{a^{2}+b^{2}+2}+\frac{b}{b^{2}+c^{2}+2}+\frac{c}{c^{2}+d^{2}+2}+\frac{d}{d^{2}+a^{2}+2}\le 1$$

I tried many attempts but still can't find the result. Attempt 1 :
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a^2+b^2+2}\leq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{ab+1}\leq\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$$
but the final term is superior to 1

Attempt 2 :
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a^2+1+b^2+1}\leq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b}=2-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{b}{a+b}=2-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{b}}.$$
So I need to prove that: $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{b}}\geq2$$
so taking $x=\frac{a}{b}$$y=\frac{b}{c}$ $z=\frac{c}{d}$ $t=\frac{d}{a}$ with $xyzt=1$

The inequality I need to prove is
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{1+x}\geq2$$
I tried using Jensen inequality to $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show your attempts for to solve this problem?

Comment: @D.md   I solved your problem and found very nice proof. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: I tried many attempts but still can't find the result.     
Attempt 1 : $$\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{a}{a^{2}+b^{2}+2}\le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{a}{ab+1}\le \frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}^{}\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$$ but the final term is superior to 1 .

Comment: Attempt 2 :

$$\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{a}{(a^{2}+1)+(b^{2}+1)}\le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{a}{a+b}=2-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{b}{a+b}=2-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{b}}$$ so I need to prove that : $$\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{b}}\ge 2$$  so taking $x=\frac{b}{a}$ $y=\frac{c}{b}$ $z=\frac{d}{c}$ $t=\frac{a}{d}$ with xyzt=1 The inequality I need to prove is $$\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{1}{1+x}\ge 2$$ I tried using Jensen inequality to $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ but it doesn't work.

Comment: Attempt 3 :

$$\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{a}{a^{2}+b^{2}+2}\le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{(a^{2}+1)}{(a^{2}+1)+(b^{2}+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{1}{1+\frac{b^{2}+1}{a^{2}+1}}=2-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}^{}\frac{1}{1+\frac{a^{2}+1}{b^{2}+1}}$$  I tried using the same approach as above but no result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By AM-GM twice we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a^2+b^2+2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a^2+1+b^2+1}\leq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)}}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{a^2+1}\cdot\frac{1}{b^2+1}}\leq\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2}{a^2+1}+\frac{1}{b^2+1}\right)=1.$$

Comment: I tried also the first inequality but I couldn't figure out to use AM-GM once again.

Comment: @D.md   Your inequality is true for any real variables.